# how to get all selected textblock values of listbox in windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, foreach, listbox

i am  selecting multiple listbox entry's using listboxselection mode=multiple and than on button-click event i am trying/want to get txtID text value using for-each loop and show message box with id printed in it for every selected items.
my listbox syntax is as below

```
<ListBox  Grid.Row="1" Name="lstAnnouncement" SelectionMode="Multiple" Width="476" d:LayoutOverrides="VerticalMargin">

        <ListBox.ItemTemplate >

            <DataTemplate>

                <StackPanel   Name="thispanel"  Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" Height="120" Width="478" >

                    <StackPanel.Background>
                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images/Text-ALU.png" Stretch="Fill" />
                        <!--<SolidColorBrush  Color="{Binding Path=background}"/>-->
                    </StackPanel.Background>

                    <Grid  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="30" Margin="0,0,0,2" Background="#FF0195D5" Height="118">
                        <!--<Grid.Background>
                            <ImageBrush ImageSource="Images/Text-ALU.png" Stretch="Fill" />
                        </Grid.Background>-->

                    </Grid>
                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="5" Height="120"/>
                    <StackPanel   Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="432" Height="114">

                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="432" Height="27">

                        </StackPanel>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="433" Height="60">
                        <TextBlock x:Name="txtID" Height="56" Text="{Binding Path=announcementID}"  TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="Black" FontSize="18.667" Width="8" Visibility="Collapsed"/>

                        </StackPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>

            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

and codebehind on click event is as below

```
  foreach (var listBoxItem in lstAnnouncement.SelectedItems)
        {
          messegebox.show(txtId.text);
          // but this(txtID) is not accessible as it is in datatemplete  
          //so how to achieve the same 

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already binding the `Text` to `announcementID`, so you should be able to get that from the `listBoxItem`. You can `Cast` it to the `Type` of your collection and eventually access the `collectionItem.announcementID` property.

The code would roughly look like

```
 foreach (var listBoxItem in lstAnnouncement.SelectedItems)
        {
          var collectionItem = listBoxItem as [YourType];
          collectionItem.announcementId; //Your required text

        }
```

Comment: hi thanks for help but i solved using this  foreach (AnnouncementData andata in lstAnnouncement.SelectedItems)
            {
                string aa = andata.announcementID.ToString();
                MessageBox.Show(aa);
            }

Answer (score 0):

i got the solution i did this

```
 foreach (AnnouncementData andata in lstAnnouncement.SelectedItems)
        {
            string aa = andata.announcementID.ToString();
            MessageBox.Show(aa);
        }
```